# "Cannot read property .. of null" after checking for undefined object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that I need to check if it is defined. Also, I also want to check if a property of that object is true or false.

So what I want is

```
if ((typeof myVar !== 'undefined') && (myVar.isMale === false)) {
     // Do something 1
 }
 else{
      // Do something 2
 }
```

But this logic gives me error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isMale' of null
```

What will be the best login to handle this condition ?

Thanks !

Comment: 'undefined' and 'null' are two different things. you are checking if the object is 'undefined' not when it is null

Comment: first check if myVar is undefined, **then**, once you know it is **not** undefined, check for its properties. In this way, if typeof myVar is undefined it **can't** have any property, therefore your if will **always** fail.

Comment: after checking 'undefined' you should check for null, if ( typedef myVar != 'undefined' && myVar !== null && myVar.isMale === false) { // do something}

Comment: Ofcourse I thought of it. But Can you express this in `if` `else` conditions. I need to have both conditions to `Do Something 1`. Else it should go to `Do Something 2`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to test further, either by exclusion:

```
if (typeof myVar != 'undefined' && myVar && myVar.isMale === false) {
```

or by inclusion:

```
if (typeof myVar == 'object' && mVar && myVar.isMale === false) {
```

but there are objects that return values other than "object" with typeof tests (e.g. host objects may and Function objects do).

or by explicit conversion:

```
if (typeof myVar != 'undefined' && Object(myVar).isMale === false) {
```

#### Edit

The additional `&& myVar` test is to catch NaN and null which pass the *typeof* test.

Comment: Thanks ! Thats a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

using optional chaining operator (?.) to access the property `isMale` of the object `myVar`. optional chaining allows safe access to the properties of an object, even if the object itself might be `null` or `undefined` rather than causing an error.

```js
if (myVar?.isMale) {
  // Do something 2
} else {
  // Do something 1
}
```